# how to implement navigational properties in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a scenario with a domain model used with NHibernate which looks kind of as below.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FirstClass : BaseClass 
{
  public virtual IList<AnotherClass> AnotherClassList  { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass : BaseClass 
{
  public virtual AnotherClass AnotherClass  { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual BaseClass MyNavigationalProperty  { get; set; }
}
```

It look nice but it does not work as I was expecting it would do. This is my scenario;

As my **first step** I am saving my FirstClass with one or many AnotherClass in the list and it works perfectly. I could retrieve my FirstClass with my related AnotherClasses in the list.

In my **second step** I am saving a new AnotherClass separately and sets MyNavigationalProperty to my FirstClass from my first step. It do looks great, but...

In my **final step** I am retrieving my FirstClass and I am expecting that my AnotherClassList contains the AnotherClass from my second step. But I only get the original AnotherClasses from my first step.

Looking into the database I can see the record from my second step but there are two separate FKs in the table AnotherClass, BaseClass_Id and FirstClass_Id, and FirstClass_Id is NULL and therefore I don't get this record in my final step.

Is this wrong way to implement navigational properties? And, if so, how should I do it properly? Or... simply, is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT**

From the question of mappings of Thilak I got another thought, The original domain model did not make use of a BaseClass, that is my implementation. Would that make it necessary to create my own mappings? Would that mean I have to totally abandon the automapping?

Comment: Could you post your mappings for the entities?

Comment: The implementation of nhibernate is inherited as part of a framework and looking at that code I noticed that it is implemented using the automapping functionality. So I don't have any mappings to share.

Comment: "I noticed that it is implemented using the automapping functionality" <--- using FluentNhibernate?

Comment: yes, sorry I wasn't clear on that one. I actually is quite new to nhibernate. I have been using EF earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reference uses another column as the collection. you can override it manually

```
class SetForeignKeyColumn : IAutomappingOverride<FirstClass>
{
    public ...
    {
        instance.HasMany(x => x.AnotherClassList).KeyColumn("baseclass_id");
    }
}
```